# If $M / (M_1 \cap M_2) \to M/M_1 \oplus M / M_2$ is an isomorphism, then $M = M_1 + M_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be submodules of an $A$-module $M$.
> Show that if
> $$
>   f
>   \colon
>   M / (M_1 \cap M_2) \rightarrow M/M_1 \oplus M/M_2 \,,
>   \quad
>   x + (M_1 \cap M_2)\mapsto (x + M_1, x + M_2)
> $$
> is an isomorphism, then $M = M_1 + M_2$.

I tried to prove that for every $x \in M$ there exists $x_1 \in M_1$ and $x_2 \in M_2$ such that $x = x_1 + x_2$.
But I couldn’t find $x_1$ and $x_2$.

The second thought is to prove $M / (M_1 + M_2) = 0$, but I failed again.

We have $M/M_1\oplus M/M_2 \simeq M/M_1 + M/M_2$, so we get $M/(M_1 \cap M_2) \simeq M/M_1 + M/M_2$.
Does this help?

Comment: What is the action of $f$ ?

Comment: Presumably $f$ comes from factoring the diagonal map $M\to M/M_1\oplus M/M_2$ through its kernel $M_1\cap M_2$? Hint: if $x=x_1+x_2$ then what is $f(x)$? Now work backwards.

Comment: @anon You mean $x+M_1\cap M_2\rightarrow  (x+M_1,x+M_2)$ ?

Comment: I'm sorry to omit the $f(x + M_1 \cap M_2) = (x + M_1, x + M_2)$

Comment: @Peter, just edit the question to include the definition of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $f(x + M_1 \cap M_2) = (x + M_1, x + M_2)$.

If this is surjective, then for each $y \in M$ there is $x \in M$ such that
$$
f(x + M_1 \cap M_2) = (x + M_1, x + M_2) = (y + M_1, 0 + M_2),
$$
so $y - x = m_1 \in M_1$ and $x  = m_2\in M_2$, so $y = m_1 + m_2 \in M_1+ M_2$.

Comment: I'm sorry to omit the $f(x + M_1 \cap M_2) = (x + M_1, x + M_2)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I do not understand why $\forall y,\exists x$, we could get $x + M_2=0 + M_2$?

Comment: @Peter, aren't you assuming $f$ to be surjective? So given *any* element $u$ of $M/M_1\oplus M/M_2$ (I am taking $u = (y + M_1, 0 + M_2)$) there is $x + M_1 \cap M_2 \in M/ M_1 \cap M_2$ such that $f(x + M_1 \cap M_2) = u$.

Comment: I understand it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Peter, you're welcome.